# Should the closed as duplicate message be changed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Here's what the closed-as-duplicate message looks like:

> **marked** as duplicate by johndoe1, johndoe2, johndoe3, johndoe4, johndoe5 May 5 '55 at 5:55
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Or something like that. Anyway, 'has been asked before' implies that the other duplicate is older, while apparently [the most relevant one should be left open, and the other one closed as duplicate.](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/is-it-ok-to-close-older-questions-as-duplicates-of-newer-ones) That means the newest question may be the one left open, and the older question marked 'has been asked before' with a link to a *newer* question.

Is that fine with everyone else? It seems like we could change it with a more accurate message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the wording you propose as it may not be clear to all users. I support the idea of providing a better phrase. Perhaps something like...

> There is another question like this which has been answered. If those
>   answers do not fully address your question,

This is a tough one to phrase cleanly due to the mix of past and conditional tenses.

Comment: I didn't propose any wording, the quote I used is the closed as duplicate message as it stands now.

Comment: I went ahead and [posted on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238520/should-the-closed-as-duplicate-message-be-altered).